# Firebase error: Domain not white listed issue for password change only

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I seem to be getting the below error, which usually indicates the Domain has not been listed in the auth'd domains in Firebase.

As you can see, the domain is in fact listed. Localhost all Firebase functions work. In production, all Firebase functions work, apart from this one. Log-in, forgotten password, email verification all working. Can't seem to find an answer that works on other questions.

Can anyone help?

[image: Firebase]

[image: App Error]

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this problem yesterday. Actually the problem was that I was passing the URL along with the email, which I guess is not needed anymore. If you have added your domain to firebase authentication then just pass your users email to the password reset method and it should work fine.